# Sourcetree existing repo has no brances and cannot create one

Tags: gitlab, repository, git-branch, atlassian-sourcetree

I have an existing repo which I connected to my gitlab via ssh

[image]

I am just trying to create my branch in sourcetree so that i push my changes there but in getting an error "not a valid object name master"

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

is there any part that i skipped because my created repository cant create new branches? thanks for reading any help will be great.

TLDR: created and linked via gitlab repo in sourcetree with an existing one, cant create branch to push

Answer (score 0):

Check first if you are creating your branch from an empty repository: there should be at least one commit.

If the repository is not empty, check if:

- your remote GitLab repository expects a default branch 'main'
- your local repository uses master as its main branch

If it is the case, rename your local branch

```
cd /path/to/local/repository
git branch -m master main
```

And make sure any future local repository starts with main:

```
git config --global init.defaultbranch main
```

Try again your branch creation in SourceTree.